# Receiving JSON in php, and using data

Tags: php, json, shopify, webhooks

I have been trying to set up a Shopify webhook ([documentation here](https://docs.shopify.com/api/guides/webhooks)) through the Shopify admin section. So far I have not been able to grab any of the data being sent in a test webhook using multiple methods, but I know it is sending because I created a Requestbin and have been seeing data come through.

I found this chunk of code here on Stackoverflow.

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $file = "log.txt";
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= $postdata;
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    echo $current;
```

So far it is the only code I have been able to use to actually see any JSON. But Im not wanting to write the JSON to the "log.txt" file every time the webhook is fired. But once I try to remove or adjust the code in anyway  I no longer see any JSON. It seems that I have to write `$postdata` to a file, and then retrieve the contents to get an array.

Is is possible to access the JSON without having to first write it to another file?

Comment: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` should be all that is needed to receive the JSON . Does `var_dump($data);` in that case not show the correct information?

Comment: `var_dump($data);` only returns `NULL` when I use `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: What do you get when you remove the json_decode?  Anything coming from php://input at all?  I wonder if some requests don't include any data or it is coming through in another format.

Comment: If I drop the json_decode and var_dump just the file_get_contents, I end up getting `string(0) ""`

Comment: For debugging, try `file_put_contents('./request.txt', print_r($_SERVER, true) . "\n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);` to see what headers and content is being sent.  Anything helpful in there?

Comment: The requests.txt file does have a lot of content in it. To be perfectly honest most of it seems above my knowledge level. At the bottom of the files it does list `[argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)

Array
(
)` Does this mean nothing is coming through?

Comment: That looks like there is neither anything sent in `$_POST`, nor in `php://input` for these requests.  Is the `REQUEST_METHOD` set to POST in the output?  A header `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256']` should also be present if they are sending information.

Comment: Something just occurred to me, I suppose I have been thinking about this all wrong. I have only been refreshing my webhook page, but not resending the webhook itself. On that note, The reason the previous code worked was because the webhook would send the POST information, and then my code would store it in the `log.txt` file. At that point I could go back and grab the JSON at anytime, because the POST information wasn't being lost on a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

So to begin, my fundamental thought process was flawed on how webhooks worked.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$file = "log.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $postdata;
file_put_contents($file, $current);

echo $current;
```

The reason this code needed to write the contents of `file_get_contents("php://input")` to the text file was because the POST request sent by the Shopify webhook, only hits the page briefly. As soon as you refresh the page, you lose all the POST data...seems obvious I know. That said I needed a way to determine if the JSON Shopify is sending out is working all fine on my server. So I created this...

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
file_put_contents('./realRequests.txt', $json->id . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

What this does is capture the ID of an order everytime Shopify fires the webhook, and wrties it to a new line in a requests file. That way you know you are able to recive working code from shopify.